WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-6.1.0) - User Does Not Get Unlocked from the Carbon Console
I have implemented the wso2is-6.1.0 as a key manager to wso2am-4.3.0 and I have implemented an authentication policy where the user gets locked on creation by setting it up in identity-mgt.properties.
# If account verification is not enabled, following property will decide where user must be lock or not after user is created 
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=true
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.Time=0
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure=true
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure.Max.Attempts=3

Additionally it could be observed that the user does not get locked on creation with the following configuration in the deployment.toml.
[event.default_listener.identity_mgt]
priority= "50"
enable = false

[event.default_listener.governance_identity_mgt]
priority= "95"
enable = true

But if I set the event.default_listener.identity_mgt enable to true, the user gets locked on creation but is not unlocked properly using the carbon console. It says user profile updated successfully, but the account locked checkbox remains the same when the profile is viewed again.

What is the correct configuration that needs to be setup in order to lock user account on creation and also to unlock the same user using the carbon console?
Thanks in advance.

It is possible to lock a user account upon creation by enabling the "Enable Account Lock On Creation" option in the User Onboarding -> Self Registration section of the Resident IDP configuration in the WSO2 IS management console. This applies to users self-registering during the self-registration flow. Alternatively, you can enable account locking globally during the self-registration configuration. To configure self-registration globally, add the following configurations to the deployment.toml file:
[identity_mgt.user_self_registration]
allow_self_registration=true
lock_on_creation=true
enable_recaptcha=true
verification_email_validity="1440"
callback_url="[${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}].*[/authenticationendpoint/login.do]*"
enable_resend_confirmation_recaptcha=true
[identity_mgt.user_self_registration.notification]
manage_internally=true

Once the user has self-registered, the account will remain locked until the user confirms their registration via the received confirmation email. Alternatively, an admin can unlock the user account using the management console in the IS.
Please refer to this 1 for more information.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.1.0/guides/identity-lifecycles/self-registration-workflow/#enable-self-registration-globally
